# Displaying data into a graph in web service ASP.NET MVC Framework

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am very new to web services and I have just recently started developing a service that receives data from a raspberry pi. All the data sent from the Raspberry Pi is stored inside the Microsoft SQL server, which I have established a connection with my web service. Right now, I am able to view the data when I click on a hyperlink, but comes out in a notepad in json format. The following is my code for the controller:

```
namespace HelloWorld.Controllers
{
    public class SecondlyReadingDatasController : ApiController
    {

        private cloudsqlEntities db = new cloudsqlEntities();

        // GET: api/SecondlyReadingDatas
        public IQueryable<SecondlyReading> GetSecondlyReadings()
        {
            SecondlyReading sec = db.SecondlyReadings.First();
            return db.SecondlyReadings;
        }
```

Below is an image of the data that I am trying to retrieve:
[image]

I have read up online that using Ajax and Highcharts can be used to display data, however, I am really confused.

My main questions are:

- Where do I implement the code for the Ajax feature? In the
  Index.cshtml or_Layout.cshtml?
- Do I need to add anything in my model or controller?
- Do I need to install any packages or libraries? I have installed
  DotNet.HighCharts already

I have tried placing the following code in the _Layout.cshtml, however, I am not getting anything:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/TestWebsite/api/SecondlyReadingDatas',
  success: function(singleSeries) {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      series: [singleSeries]
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

I am not sure if this is the complete set of code that is required only. I have tried looking at the following links, but I am having a hard time understanding as this is my first time working on Ajax. Would appreciate any assistance

Referenced links:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1f3f2a/charting-in-mvc/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820349/Highcharts-in-asp-net-using-jquery-ajax
[Load data into Highcharts with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223972/load-data-into-highcharts-with-ajax)

https://csharptrenches.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/how-to-use-highcharts-js-with-asp-net-mvc-4/

[creating highchart with ajax json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236113/creating-highchart-with-ajax-json-data)

[HighCharts load data via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157693/highcharts-load-data-via-ajax)

Comment: This article should be helpful: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820349/Highcharts-in-asp-net-using-jquery-ajax.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you have to replace 'container' with the id of an element (the contianer) which will contain the chart...

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
```

So if you had a

```
<div id='chartContainer'></div>
```

Then you can change it to;

```
Highcharts.chart('chartContainer', {
```

Comment: Where do I place the Highcharts.chart('chartContainer', {