# how can I convert my chart data creation in AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, highcharts

this is my code which creates a highchart chart.I want to convert the data which makes the chart in AJAX Callback because I want to make my chart a live chart which updates every minute.And the only way to do that is via ajax callback. How can I achieve that.something  that closely resembles is  like this http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/j4ZYB/

````
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/drag-panes.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/oi chart.css">

</head>
<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>

<script type="text/javascript">
  
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        chart: {
            height: (1 / 2 * 100) + '%' // 1:2 ratio
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true,
            selected: customRange,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1D'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: '1W'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 2,
                text: '2W'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }]
        },
        time: {
            timezoneOffset: timezone
        },
        title: {
            text: chartTitle,

        },
        subtitle: {
            text: subTitle,
        },
        yAxis: {
            offset: 60,
            title: {
                text: 'Open Interest'
            },
            resize: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {


                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                label: {
                    connectorAllowed: false
                },

            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Expected',
            data: [<% for(var i=0; i < expected_data.length; i++) { %> [<%= expected_data[i] %>], <% } %>].sort()

        }, {
            name: 'Actual',
            data: [<% for(var i=0; i < actual_data.length; i++) { %> [<%= actual_data[i] %>], <% } %>].sort()

        }],


        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }

    });
</script>

</html>```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157693/highcharts-load-data-via-ajax

Comment: yes it is similar but what goes in the url...is it the location where data is processed..am i right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach to achieve the wanted output. I think that everything is explained very well in the code. Here the chart is not dynamic, because the data is a static JSON online storage link.

```
//create the initial chart
let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: []
});

//the chart is update every each 3 seconds
setInterval(function() {
  fetch("https://api.npoint.io/cc798213da33bfead2d6")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonData => {
      // define series variable
      const series = [{
        data: jsonData.data1
      }, {
        data: jsonData.data2
      }];

      //update chart series config
      chart.update({
        series: series
      }, true, true, true)
    });
}, 3000);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bs5Ltdo0/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: can you tell me what goes into the fetch URl. form my understanding it is the Url from where the data is processed, right?

Comment: can you tell me how can i convert my data into url it is in array of arrays

Comment: The URL points to a page that returns json, the link Sebastian used shows the format to follow for highcharts.  How you generate that data is up to you.

Comment: Hi i am still not able to pass data in json format can you give an example similar to my situation for better understanding

Comment: @ness how your data is generating?

Comment: from a js file where multiple sql queries run to form a query which will be sent to the database to fetch the data and it will be displayed in ejs file the code of which is above in the `[<% for(var i=0; i < expected_data.length; i++) { %> [<%= expected_data[i] %>], <% } %>].sort()` and this loc will display the data

Comment: `[<% for(var i=0; i < expected_data.length; i++) { %> [<%= expected_data[i] %>], <% } %>].sort()` does this part of the code work?

Comment: yes it works for end of day data and whenevr we reload the page it gives acc data

Comment: @ness so if this part of the code works maybe you can try this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xahy1mdu/